# When voting to migrate an off-topic question, why is the list of sites limited?

Tags: discussion, migration

Earlier, I voted to close [this question about Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055231/wordpress-downloadable-exes) as off-topic.  The question has since been closed.

There is an [SE site for Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com), but it didn't show up in the list when I selected "off-topic".

The options were:

- Meta Stack Overflow
- Server Fault
- Super User
- Webmasters
- Programmers

**Questions:**

- Should Wordpress appear in this list?
- Are there any other sites that should appear in the list?
- Should all non-beta sites appear in that list by default?

Comment: +1. The problem here is that the list really doesn't cover the common requirements. Virtually all the questions want to I vote to close as Off Topic I have to be leave them as just simply Off Topic, without a migration option because the appropriate site to move them to is not in the list of options.

Comment: Hi @Spudley, now that I've been around a little longer, I agree with [Robert Harvey's point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79961/155826).  I don't participate on Wordpress SE, so I don't really know what their community requires in good Q&A. Additionally, most questions that are closed as off-topic most likely aren't that great to begin with, so we'd likely be migrating garbage. However, in the rare occasion that there's a really outstanding but off-topic question, flag it for mod attention.  They're usually happy to move stuff that is of good quality. :)

Comment: About the garbage, just hang around on MSO for awhile and look for a user to accidentally post a programming question on meta; it happens several times a day.  You'll see exactly what I mean. Most of those posts are garbage questions, so they just get closed and deleted.

Comment: Hmm, yes agreed. But your comment gives me a thought: Maybe the list of migration targets should be tailored to include sites that the user is active in (ie the user making the close request). That way, it could still be limited to a short list, but would be sites that I'm familiar with, so I would know more about whether they're suited to migration (the current list only has one that I know anything about). It would also increase the hit rate, because I'm more likely to be reading questions that are in my field of interest.

Comment: @Spudley - That's a really great idea! For instance, if you have at least X reputation on the site, it could appear in the migration path. You should post that as a feature request.

Comment: I think I will suggest it.... :-)

Comment: I agree with the idea that you can recommend migration to a site where have enough reputation.

Comment: i still wish https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be in there..

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The list of sites is limited because many people who vote to migrate do not fully understand the scope of the target site, or migrate questions that are of marginal quality, so many questions get migrated when they shouldn't be.  This is further illustrated in [Jeff Atwood's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79964/21960).

Moderators do have this capability.  If you do not have this capability in your "close as off topic" dialog, flag the question for moderator attention, with a comment specifying which site the question should be moved to, and we will migrate it if it is appropriate to do so.

Comment: Perhaps this answer would be helpful to have in the UI itself.

Comment: So, looks like we're lacking a feature, the ability to choose from a larger list of sites (I wouldn't mind preconfiguring my own list or having the entire list). Is there a place where this feature can be voted for? I don't think we need to bother moderators with manual moving of questions.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Perhaps I wasn't specific enough.  I've modified my answer to make it more specific to the question that was asked.

Comment: You know, Robert, while this may have some sense on SO, on ELU it becomes ludicrous, since we have one and only one migration option there: to the meta. That’s really annoying; even if non-mods can’t migrate, we should at the least be able to ***nominate*** a target SE site. The “belongs on another SE site” offtopic choice is otherwise just so much bait-and-switch. Why the heck should it have a second menu that gives you exactly one option? That makes no sense!

Comment: Who has the ability to modify the list of suggested migration destinations?

Comment: @Jim: The SE development team.  For EL&U the best option is to cast a custom moderator flag, and have the moderators migrate it.

Comment: @Robert I ask in response to this http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/how-can-we-migrate-questions-to-other-se-sites/2113?noredirect=1#comment3255_2113

Comment: If people who migrate don't understand the scope of the site, then I would say that there's a problem with that specific site. http://programmers.stackexchange.com stands out as the perfect example. That's the most likely site where SO users tend to drop all questions that aren't obviously technical. But I don't even think the people who hang out at Programmers actually know what scope that site has, as the massive numbers of closed posts there clearly indicates. My point is: the close-migrate system on SO shouldn't be suffering just because there are problems with the external sites.

Comment: I don't see why not have the dialog have the option to suggest migration to any site, but for some sites require moderator intervention for the migration. Much better than having reviewers indicate the suggested destination in an arbitrary comment.

Answer (score 14):

This question would actually be off topic at wordpress.se, because it is about the specifics of free hosting limitations at http://wordpress.com and not wordpress itself.

In other words, this question is really a wordpress.com (the site itself, its free hosting) support question.

That's one reason why we don't unlock unusual migration paths.. only common ones.

Comment: That's kind of a non-answer though, isn't it. What if it had been a bona fide question?

Comment: Are the given list of sites still the most common paths? Statistically.

Comment: Seems as though questions that do pertain to Wordpress are quite commonly posted on StackOverflow but one could also argue that often times the Wordpress question is actually just a PHP question.