# List of target sites in flagging wizard

Tags: support, migration, close-reasons, off-topic

As a non-moderator, I can flag questions for a multitude of reasons. One is "It doesn't belong here" and then "off topic". After that, a list of possibly suited SE sites is shown along with a generic item.

Who manages this list and how can we influence it?

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited/79964#79964) by Jeff seems to indicate that the respective community does not have control over the list of target sites. Is this correct? If so, can it be changed?

**Edit:** Crossposted on [meta.cstheory.SE](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/list-of-target-sites-in-flagging-wizard)

Comment: Jon, did you misunderstand the question? You changed tag to close-reasons while I was specifically referring to the flagging dialog. According to our mods, you can suggest *any* SE site when issuing a close vote, so there is no issue there.

Comment: If you look closely, when you select "it doesn't belong here", through the flag dialog, it changes to the close reasons dialog. So it's not actually flagging. Mods have the ability to migrate anywhere in the network, but normal users do not. If you want to suggest a site other than the ones listed, you have to flag for moderator attention. You can't directly vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the respective community does not have control over the list of target sites. Is this correct?

Correct. The community does not have *direct* control of the list.

I believe the procedure is to discuss which sites you, as a community, want to appear in that list: this would be done on the specific Meta site (which you've already started to do -- good). If there is consensus, then a site moderator will raise the issue with management to get the list physically changed.

Comment: Please also bear in mind that there are only 5 migration slots on the migrate dialog and one of them **has** to be the site's meta. You'll have to make a **really** good case to replace one of the existing ones

Comment: On cstheory.SE, we only have our meta and SO, so plenty of room. What are the reasons for the limit of 5 and for not allowing the communities to manage the lists?

Comment: @Raphael: In the answer you linked to in your question, Jeff pretty much answers the first part. For the latter, you'd have to ask him about that directly.