# Off-topic option should include all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites)
>   [More options when flagging for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration)

At the moment, when you vote to close a question when it's **off-topic**, you can only vote to move it to one of these sites:

```
meta.stackoverflow.com  
serverfault.com  
superuser.com  
webmasters.stackexchange.com  
programmers.stackexchange.com
```

But sometimes the question is really a good one, but it would fit some other Stack Exchange site. And new users rarely know the difference.
For example:

```
http://codereview.stackexchange.com  
http://math.stackexchange.com
http://scicomp.stackexchange.com
http://cstheory.stackexchange.com
http://android.stackexchange.com
http://webapps.stackexchange.com
```

Anyway, I think giving the whole range of Stack Exchange sites in the **off-topic** option will help reduce the load on Stack Overflow and direct people to right sites.

Comment: Yeah, let's make the list searchable.

Comment: You can always suggest another site for migration through a general "this requires moderator attention" message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites), related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited

Comment: Just flag and say "Belongs on SU.SE" or "belongs on Judiasm". A giant list is too intimidating.

Comment: I'm sure that the that users that have enough points to vote to close would know a bit of the other sites. And if you're voting to migrate, i'm sure you have a site in mind.

Comment: Heck no! There are well over [220 pages worth](http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=220&tab=reputation&filter=all) of users with close voting abilities just on Stack Overflow alone.  That equates to more than 7920 (220*9*4) users to potentially get it wrong. The majority of those users don't _really_ know if it belongs on another site, they only _think_ it belongs there because of the title. It takes at least 3 people to get it wrong, most of the time the first person influences the others to make the same wrong choice. If any of them participated here, they'd know not to migrate crap!

Comment: Yes, good idea. I always want to move the bike-shed questions to http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you feel a closed question has a better home elsewhere, please flag it for moderation attention and ask for it to be migrated. It's unrealistic to expect SOpedians to be familiar with every site's scope and decide whether it would fit there.

From the current migration targets, Programmers is the site which overlaps mostly in expertise with Stack Overflow. However 1 out of 3 questions that got migrated from Stack Overflow to Programmers got closed, and a very large number of the ones that remained open are of very low quality.

If anything, please remove Programmers from the list of migration targets.

Comment: I'm sure that the SOpedians, as you call them, that have enough points to vote to close would know a bit of the other sites. And if you're voting to migrate, i'm sure you have a site in mind.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer And I'm pretty sure they don't. Again, 34% of questions migrated from SO to P.SE are rejected, and P.SE is about the same topics as SO, just from a different perspective. How can you realistically expect software developers to understand the scope of sites like Cognitive Sciences or Bicycles if a large number of them seems to fail to understand (or bother to) the scope of a site dedicated to software development?