# When trying to close a question as off topic, the obvious choice for "Belongs on" does not come up

Tags: feature-request, support, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When Voting to Migrate an Off-Topic Question, Why Is the List of Sites Limited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited)

I just came across [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955862/camal-query-soap-sharepoint) that would have been much better suited for the SharePoint.StackExchange.com site.  The question had SharePoint in the title and was tagged as SharePoint, but when I was presented with the choices for sites to migrate it to, several SE sites that had nothing to do with question were given as options, but not the obvious one (SharePoint):

[image]

What criteria is being used to determine which sites are presented here?  Could it be improved to include obvious choices or allow for people to select which site it belongs on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the top four migration targets (plus Meta) are listed there. The list is occasionally adjusted, but there are no plans to make the list longer.

Simply flag for Moderator attention and choose the "Other" option to explain where it should be migrated to.