# Why has Pro Webmasters been removed from off-topic close options?

Tags: feature-request, support, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update Migration Path List for Non-Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators)

If I vote to close a question as off-topic, Pro Webmasters used to be in the list of sites to migrate the question to, but it's no longer there. **How can we move questions to Pro Webmasters?**

Also, a suggestion: Perhaps the list of sites could change based on the question's tags? For example the `seo` tag is more likely to be suited for PW than DBA or Tex.

Comment: You can still leave a custom flag message on the question informing a moderator that migration to Pro Webmasters might be appropriate.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79960/147645