# Flag a question as being off-topic and belonging on another SE site (which is not in the suggested list)

Tags: discussion

I have [come across a question which looks like it would be better suited for CodeReview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413365/improve-vba-code-excel), and so went to flag it as such, but after clicking "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate" and "off topic," I get the following.

[image: Screenshot]

I think the question is more suited to Code-Review than any of the sites listed, but there doesn't seem to be an option to flag the question as "belongs on CodeReview." I am sure there is a good reason for this, and am curious to know what it is.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited?rq=1

Comment: This is a huge problem, for now you just have to flag it.

Comment: Flag it with a "custom" reason, something like "migrate to xyz.SE"

Answer (score 2):

Flag it for moderation attention.
Keep in mind that moderators cannot migrate too old questions, and that a bad question is generally not migrated. Also, if a question suits two different sites, it is generally migrated if the OP asks for it, not when another user asks for its migration.

Comment: I have done that, I don't think its a bad question, just thought the user would benefit more from the question being on CodeReview, and probably wasn't aware the site existed, cheers

Comment: By bad question I mean a question that would be closed as not constructive, or not a real question; I would also add "too localized," but I think that what a site would judge too localized, another site would see differently.

Answer (score 1):

It's not always beneficial to have other sites show up in the list. A prime example is Programmers, which used to be on the list for migration from StackOverflow but no longer is. As I understand it, lots of people on SO would mark questions for migration to Programmers because they were off topic for SO but still seemed related to programming. Understandable, but Programmers isn't just a catch-all for everything that contains the word "computer" and isn't appropriate for SO, and the volume of incorrect migrations was becoming a problem, so they removed Programmers from the list.

You can still get questions migrated to Programmers, of course; there's just not an automatic way to suggest that. Instead, flag the question and add a message to the moderator suggesting the migration. It'd probably make things a little easier on the mods if you add a quick explanation of why the question is appropriate for Programmers. Same goes for other sites like Code Review.