# Off Topic Close vote suggest a SE website besides the 5 listed

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration, off-topic

I see on [When voting to migrate an off-topic question, why is the list of sites limited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited), that it is a concern to allow user migration to any SE site based on users' understanding of the other site. Just now I came across [this off topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086831/how-to-increase-ubuntu-partition) on Stack Overflow that should belong on Ask Ubuntu.

If the sites should not all be added to `Close -> Off Topic`, can there be a drop-down menu to flag a moderator about the question and write-in which site it belongs on?

Comment: You can flag as "other" and say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flag it.**

If you think the question is a *strong fit* for another site, flag it and add a custom message of what you think.