# How do you flag a question as off topic if it belongs on unix SE?

Tags: support, flags, migration, off-topic

I saw a question on SO that belonged on unix.stackexchange.com. Previously, I could flag it as off-topic and specify that it belonged on another SE site. Usually a dialog would give me the option to specify which other SE site it belonged on, but unix.stack.exchange was never on the list, so I selected "Other".

Today when I tried to do this, there was no "Other" option. Only options for meta, superuser, tex, dba, and sharepoint.

Is it possible to flag a question that belongs on any other site besides those listed?

Here it seems clear I should select "It doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate..."

[image]

And then "off-topic because..."

[image]

And then "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network."

[image]

Dead end

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: [When Voting to Migrate an Off-Topic Question, Why Is the List of Sites Limited?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79960)

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Flag it and use the "other" option to explain where it should go and why. Moderators can migrate questions to any site in the network.<sup>1</sup><sup>2</sup>

[image: flagging dialog]

<sup>1</sup> Assuming the post isn't over 60 days old *and* the Moderator agrees with you.

<sup>2</sup> Remember the first rule of migrations: Don't migrate crap.

Comment: Won't most people when viewing this dialog be led down the rabbit-hole (which I updated in my question with pictures) at this point by selecting "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate..."?

Sure once you get all the way down and there is no option to select, it may make sense to some to come back to the top and use "other", but I got the impression that if it didn't belong on one of the specified sites that was listed, I shouldn't be flagging it at all. Seems a failing of UI to me.

Comment: I'm not addressing whether or not the UI is flawed. I'm merely pointing out the process to request a migration to a site that's not in the default migration list. If you want to suggest an improvement to the UI by all means post a [tag:feature-request] question.

Comment: I see. "That's not a bug, that's a feature."

Comment: Done http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188447/allow-user-to-flag-a-question-as-belonging-on-a-specific-site-specified-by-user