# What decides, which sites will appear on Off-Topic list?

Tags: discussion, migration

I was trying to migrate my own question (finally deleted it and reposted) to *Programmers* only to find out, that when I select `Closing > Off-Topic > Migration` there is no *Programmers* on the list and the list itself is limited to only five strange sites:

[image]
*Strange* (at least for me), because:

1. None of the selected pages seems to fit my question.
2. There aren't many popular SE website on the list (maybe except second -- *Super User*).
3. I haven't been ever using three (last) out of five suggested.

**What decides, which sites will appear on this list**? <s>Why there is only five, not all of them. And finally -- how to migrate a question to a site, that is no listed there?</s>

Comment: I have re-edited to question to narrow it only to thing, that is not explained in linked question -- what decides, which sites will appear? As I analyse question, I'm asking about, there is virtually nothing, that could judge suggesting, that it should be redirected to any site, that was proposed to me. It is clearly addressed to either Stack Overflow (where it already sits) or to Programmers, nowhere else.

Comment: @trejder the list is re-evaluated based on the number of successful migrations (that is migrations that are not closed by the destination community).  Programmers used to be on the list but was removed because of this.

Comment: While I understand the case and arguments behind, I still think, that it makes this tool completely useless. I'm so happy, that Tex or Sharepoint societies has accepted _so many_ migrations, but it doesn't change the fact, that there are _so little_ questions, that could be migrated there. If there is a problem with this tool, then it should be turned off at all -- leaving it only to moderators to decide -- as in current shape it is useless.

Comment: @trejder as in [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79961/173052) answer, you can flag it for migration so moderators can do it if it fits.

Comment: @FallenAngel I understand. I only suggest, that in current shape, this  tool is useless for the end users (I'm not talking about moderators). It lists pages that are very rarely used (in comparison to _Programmers_ for example). I understand reasons, why this happens (large number of migration rejections on other sites) and that there are other ways to report question to migrate. I just say, that in current circumstances this tool is useless.