# How to migrate a question from Stackoverflow to some other sites like superuser?

Tags: discussion, migration, migrated-questions

I asked some questions on stackoverflow and then I came to know they were better to be asked on the other sites like superuser or database administrator. While searching on those sites I saw phrases like *Migrated from stackoverflow*. So how does it happen? Can I choose a question to migrate (if yes, how?) or anybody else is to decide that?

Comment: Related... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited

Comment: Since 15rep, you can participate to migrate an off-topic question, see flag-posts: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main ways this can happen.  Each site can have up to 5 established migration paths to non-beta sites if they frequently have questions asked that fit those sites.  Then, anyone who is able to cast a close vote (or even an off-topic flag) has the option to say that it belongs on one of those 5 sites.

Alternately, moderators on a site can close a question as belonging on any other SE site and it will send the question over.

Generally the requirements for this to occur is that it is a good fit on the target site and would not be a duplicate.

Please note that in situations like this, you should NOT post the same question simultaneously on two sites.  Either delete the question asked in the wrong place (if there aren't any good answers yet) and recreate it on the correct place or flag it for moderator attention and ask for migration after verifying that the question isn't already asked on the target site.

Comment: +1, but the last paragraph reads a little contradictory. You say not to post the same question again, then say to post it again if you delete the original.

Comment: @BlueIce - good point, altered the language to clarify that we want to avoid having the same question active on two sites (where it could get two different sets of answers) at the same time.

Comment: It looks great now :)

Answer (score 1):

Questions are migrated to other sites if site members [who have 3000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) vote to close the question - but suggest that it is best served to move the question to another site. I am pretty confident that a moderator can move these as well - without the community interaction on it.

If they have been answered though, probably best to leave them where they are. You do have the option to delete them - however if there are answers there already, it woudn't be good form - or it might even be stopped by the site if there are upvotes on the answers given.