# How do I (or should I) migrate a question about the Arduino to the Arduino site?

Tags: discussion, migration

I spotted a [question about the Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448327/i2c-addresses-63-are-not-usable-with-attiny85) on the StackOverflow site. The question was pretty specific about Arduino hardware, however I don't have the rep to migrate it to the [Arduino beta](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) site.

What is the appropriate action here?

- Flag it? I can only flag for moderator attention at present.
- Ignore it and hope someone else flags or migrates it?
- Answer it, even though it is better answered on the dedicated site?

That question certainly isn't the first which is rather specific to the Arduino platform.

---

*Because this was flagged as a possible duplicate, edited to add*:

Comments below indicate that voting to move the question is already available. However I don't have the rep to vote to close. I have a lot more rep on the [target site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448327/i2c-addresses-63-are-not-usable-with-attiny85). But I can't vote to "pull" the question to it, I would need have to have rep here to "push" it (which I don't).

> But are you sure the Arduino community wants it?

I am currently ranked #6 for the year and #1 for the quarter on the Arduino site. I am also a moderator on the [Arduino forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/). Yes, I believe the question is more applicable to the Arduino site. It specifically mentions the ATtiny85 processor, I<sup>2</sup>C, and a particular Arduino library.

Being a moderator myself on another site, I don't particularly want to pester the moderators here with requests to migrate *this*, *that* and *the other* question every day.

So basically this question is about: is there an easy way to do this without involving the moderators?

Comment: Custom-flag is the only thing you got. But are you sure the Arduino community wants it? I mean, have you got their approval, or the OP's approval, through comments/meta?

Comment: There's an answer to that in this question: [When voting to migrate an off-topic question, why is the list of sites limited?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited)

Answer (score 5):

If you are absolutely sure, 100% sure, no doubt at all... then flag the question for moderator attention (the bottom custom flag). The overall summary of this flag is:

> A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!

Migration is a another flag in which you can use but the site you listed is probably not there at all. So the custom flag should help you at this point. Whether the flag is approved or not, that is up to the moderators to decide now.

In [Robert Harvey's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79961/278543), he sums up what you need to do in order to try to migrate your question to the site that you think it is more appropriate in:

> Moderators do have this capability. If you do not have this capability in your "close as off topic" dialog, flag the question for moderator attention, with a comment specifying which site the question should be moved to, and we will migrate it if it is appropriate to do so.