# A more flexible flagging option would be nice to have

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I was trying to flag a post on Information Security as off-topic. I thought that the post would be better suited for the Programmers Stack Exchange where people discuss careers and stuff.

Expected flow: when I choose "belongs to another Stack exchange Site", I would be given a list of Stack Exchange sites to choose from.

Actual result: I am shown a list of Stack Exchange sites closely related to the Information Security site.

Probably a case of usability versus advanced features.

**Edit**.
One of the comments says that the website has the same behaviour ( I use the app mostly and actually dont event have laptop access right now) If it's actually the case, I would prefer such an option there too.

Comment: It's working same way as on the site. I don't think the app users should get more power than ordinary site users, it won't be fair.

Comment: I rarely use the site. I prefer the app so I don't know much about the website

Comment: Fair enough. Still, this request will be declined, you can learn about the reason for limiting the migration list [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just flag the question as *in need of moderator attention*, and explain to which site it should be migrated.

Because successful migrations are relatively rare, only the most common targets are shown; there's room for the site's Meta and four other Stack Exchange sites. Choosing from five sites is a lot easier than having to browse/search a list. Apparently, Programmers is not among the most popular migration targets for Information Security.

Comment: That definitely is a good work around. Not sure if it's a solution

Comment: Based on @shadowwizard 's comment, I believe your answer solves the problem